Angular Reactive Forms logic error with multiple radio-buttons
I am facing the following situation:
I am building an app for surveys that has the following structure:
A survey can have multiple pages, each with questions. Amid multiple possible question types, there is one where you can select a single choice of predefined answers. Any number of answers can have an 'Other' answer, where the user can type his own answer instead of using a predefined value.
You can see a simplified reproduction here and get more familiar with what I will explain:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-2l8qgw?file=src%2Fapp%2Fcontainer-page%2Fquestion-container%2Fquestion-container.component.html
I am using Reactive forms to track all of the survey form changes so when a user changes a page and comes back, his selected answers persist the chosen values. I group each question along with a Form Group that tracks the answer state for that question.
The issue I am facing is related to the Other answers. There are also other issue such as variables not reinitialising when changing the page but the main issue is with the first page question. As you can see, the first answer is initially selected and it remains selected whatever you click on
There are more comments about the code in the reproducer. In short, due to the nature of the app logic I need to store in the Form group both the value of a predefined answer as well as the value of the selected Other answer value.
I have to use a custom logic to check the radio button of an Other answer since its value can always change. For that, I use otherSgChoiceIndexes to keep track of the index at which each Other answers is, and otherSgChoiceValues to use with [(ngModel)] to manually check/uncheck these radio buttons.
Overall this logic works as expected but as you can see by inspecting with Angular devtools, even is the associated value for the first radio button is initially false, it is checked. I believe it may be due to [value]="$index" but I haven't been able to figure a solution yet. You can see that the first answer will always be checked regardless of clicking other inputs.
I want to be able to have a correct behaviour for these Other answers
